# Why is the elseif statement failing?

Tags: php, string

What am I missing here? It puts the APT in red but doesn't find the LOT occurrences. If I remove the elseif statement all together and change the APT to LOT it works fine for the LOT occurrences. Why won't it find both?

```
    if (strrchr($row["Address"], "APT") == true)    {
        $keyword = "APT";
        $addr = preg_replace('/\b' . preg_quote($keyword) . '\s*\w+/i', ', <span style="color:red;">$0</span>', $row['Address']);
    }
    elseif (strrchr($row["Address"], "LOT") == true)    {
        $keyword = "LOT";
        $addr = preg_replace('/\b' . preg_quote($keyword) . '\s*\w+/i', ', <span style="color:red;">$0</span>', $row['Address']);
    }   
    else {
    $addr = $row["Address"];
    }
```

Comment: What are some examples of values of `$row["Address"]` which work and don't work?

Comment: [`strrchr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) is a character search, not a string search. You need to using something like [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) instead.

Comment: The code displays great. I just added the LOT elseif statement to display lot numbers the same as APT numbers. But it is disregarding it.

Comment: Thanks Tigger. I get the approach but even still my problem is with the elseif statement because, alone, both find the needle just fine.

Comment: NO! Your `strrchr` calls do NOT work “fine”. You are actually only searching for “A” and “L”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, since the patterns are the same, and the replacement is the same for both APT and LOT, you could just put them both into the same `preg_replace` call.

The if/elseif seems redundant to me anyway since the pattern won't match and nothing will be replaced if those keywords aren't in the string.

```
$addr = preg_replace('/\b(?:LOT|APT)\s*\w+/i', ', <span style="color:red;">$0</span>', $row['Address']);
```

Comment: So simple. Thank you. I still don't understand why that statement was failing. I just hate not understanding.

Comment: Since `strchr()` is only searching for _the first character_ of APT, it's going to execute the `if` block instead of the `elseif` block if the string contains an A (and it looks like all of the strings in your screenshot do). It will do the `preg_replace()` in that `if` block, but nothing will be replaced unless the entire APT string is there.

Comment: That's what I needed to sleep tonight. THANK you. And thanks Tigger for your time spent laying that all out.

Comment: Pleasant dreams. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[`strrchr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) is a character search, not a string search. You need to use something like [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) instead.

For example:

```
if (strrchr('ABC','AB')){
  echo 'found';
}
```

And

```
if (strrchr('ABC','BA')){
  echo 'found';
}
```

Both display `found` as the first character in the needle (`A` in the first, and `B` in the second) are found.

If you want to find a string instead of a character match, you need to use something like `strpos()` instead.

```
if (strpos('ABC','AB') !== false){
  echo 'found';
}
```

And

```
if (strpos('ABC','BA') !== false){
  echo 'found';
}
```

Only the first example will display `found`. Note: You need to use `!== false` as `strpos()` will return either the string position or `false`.

Comment: I can rewrite that code but that's not going to solve my problem. The way the code is written currently I can find what I am looking for. Without the elseif statement it finds the APT rows every single time and formats them in red. If I change the APT portion to LOT it will find the LOT rows every single time. But if I use the elseif statement its not finding both at the same time. That's what I can't wrap my brain around.